# use mock for 2 function and same answer

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mockito, mockk

I have A class

```
class A{
    fun b():String{ return "b"}
    fun c():String{ return "c"}
    fun d():String{ return "d"}
}
```

I use Mockk or Mockito for UnitTest. I need to return all function "checkForTest".

I use this way.

```
@Test
fun test() {
        val a: A = mockk()
        
        every {
            a.b()
        } answers {
            "checkForTest"
        }
        every {
            a.c()
        } answers {
            "checkForTest"
        }
        every {
            a.d()
        } answers {
            "checkForTest"
        }
        
        println(a.b())
        println(a.c())
        println(a.d())
}
```

can I use this way?

```
@Test
fun test() {
        val a: A = mockk()

        every {
            a.b()
            a.c()
            a.d()
        } answers {
            "checkForTest"
        }
        println(a.b())
        println(a.c())
        println(a.d())
}
```

I need the same answer for 3 functions in every.

Comment: Havent seen that on the docs, I wonder what happend when you did it?... maybe it wont work because `every` receives a lambda so you are padding a lambda that is the last function